# Issue with tasks on Windows Server Task Scheduler set to fire every minute

Tags: windows-server-2019, task-scheduler

Windows Server 2019 Standard.

I set some tasks on Task Scheduler to run every minute.
They apparently worked fine, but I found out that sometimes there are "holes" in the executions, even of 15 minutes.

For some of the tasks this is not a big deal, but I have a task in particular for which it is critical that is ran with a certain frequency.

The settings of this task are:

- general: run whether user is logged on or not,
- triggesr: at 17:40 every day. After triggered, repeat every 1 minute for a duration of 1 day,
- actions: .bat file execution,
- conditions: all default,
- settings: all default, run task as soon as possibile after a scheduled task is missed.

The .bat uses WGET to call an Action of my .NET Core application running in IIS through a HTTP GET call.
I have noticed the issue looking at the IIS logs because sometimes I do not see these GETs.
I enabled the Task Scheduler history and I do see these holes with no apparent explanation ([Task Scheduler history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWjgo.png)).
The other similar tasks (they all use the same mechanism with WGET) are also not ran in the same periods so I'm tempted to exclude issues in my code.
I've not checked every call, but in general the calls ends in way less than a minute, usually in milliseconds or a couple of seconds at max, so they always finish before the next execution.

Probably for delicate tasks such as mine I should have not used the Task Scheduler at all and in fact I'm now looking for an alternative, but I'm interested in knowing why there are these holes in the Task Scheduler executions and what can I check in order to obtain more informations.
I looked at the System logs, but I found nothing in particular when there are these "holes".